# Change text in h/div/span, etc. trough css where text=xxx

Tags: css

Is it possible to get a `h`/`div`/`span`, etc. where the text=xxx?

Example: `<h2>Advertisement</h2>`

Is it possible to get all `<h2>` where the text is `"Advertisement"` and set it `display:none` trough CSS?

Comment: "Pure" CSS? No, it is not possible.

Comment: @acdcjunior you are perfectly right. I wanted only to point out that in CSS3 selectors once there was a `contains` pseudo class, that would be the answer to this question. It has been dropped, it was defined in an old draft: http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#content-selectors.

Comment: once, the idea was on its way with the pseudo :contains()  http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#content-selectors ...

Comment: @GCyrillus Wow, I beat you by just 10 seconds!

Comment: i like your link best :)

Answer (score 2):

Not with plain CSS, but if you are using jQuery, try this:

```
$( "h:contains('Advertisement')" ).css( "display", "none" );
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do it with pure CSS is:

```
.ad{
  display:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ad">Advertisement</div>
<h1 class="ad">Advertisement</h1>
```